# VBA coding to select specific reference object library

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access database originally written in 2010 (but has been updated to 2013) with specific VBA code to format a word document. The database is located on a shared network and I have some users with Access 2013 and some users with 2010.  How do I make the database reference ONLY use the 2010 reference libraries?  Or have it reference only specific reference libraries? The Microsoft office 14 object reference libraries work in both 2010 and 2013. But of course the version 15 object reference libraries do not.  the obvious answer is to upgrade everyone, which is slowly being done, but I have some users going through a legacy citrix server that cannot be upgraded.

I am new to VBA coding, and I think "late binding"  code will work, but I am not sure how to go about creating it and where is the best place to put the code.  The letter must be formatted in a specific format based on our Division's specifications.

this also my first post-so please let me know if I need to explain the problem in more detail.  Below is the code to open the letter, make sure it is formatted correctly and has the needed fields from the database.

```
Private Sub btnGenLetter_Click()

'This part just makes sure required info is filled in and prompts user to fill in if not
'If you want to use this, of course you will have to substitute the correct path and name
'of the fields being checked.
'If UserForm1.TextBox5.Value = "" Then
'    UserForm1.Label4.BackColor = vbRed
'    UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0
'    MsgBox "Please enter Case Manager's Name."
'    Exit Sub
'    Else
'    UserForm1.Label4.BackColor = &H8000000F
'End If
'If UserForm1.TextBox6.Value = "" Then
'    UserForm1.Label9.BackColor = vbRed
'    UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0
'    MsgBox "Please enter Case Manager's Address."
'    Exit Sub
'    Else
'    UserForm1.Label9.BackColor = &H8000000F
'End If
'If UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
'    UserForm1.Label6.BackColor = vbRed
'    UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0
'    MsgBox "Please specify a Participant Support Specialist."
'    Exit Sub
'    Else
'    UserForm1.Label6.BackColor = &H8000000F
'End If
'If Letter1.TextBox3.Value = "" Then
'    Letter1.Label10.BackColor = vbRed
'    MsgBox "Please give the Specific Review Request."
'    Exit Sub
'    Else
'    Letter1.Label10.BackColor = &H8000000F
'End If
'If Letter1.TextBox4.Value = "" Then
'    Letter1.Label23.BackColor = vbRed
'    MsgBox "Please give the specific reason for denial."
'    Exit Sub
'    Else
'    Letter1.Label23.BackColor = &H8000000F
'End If

' Initial Letter No Follow-up
Dim WDApp As Word.Application ' Object
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document ' Object
Dim Temp As String
Dim intTab As Integer


On Error GoTo Err_btnGenLetter_Click

Set WDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Temp = "\\lowchen\files\DDD\Shared Directories\All Waivers Shared\Adverse Action Database\BHD Letterhead - 2011.doc"
WDApp.Documents.Open FileName:=Temp, ReadOnly:=True

WDApp.Visible = True

With WDApp
    With .Selection
        .Font.Size = 12
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
        .TypeText Text:=Format(Date, "mmmm dd, yyyy")
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight ' 2
        .TypeText Text:="Ref:" & " "
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .Font.Size = 12
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0
        .TypeText Text:=Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![Guardian name] & " "
        .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:=Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![guardian address] & " "
        .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:=Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![guardian city] & " " & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![guardian state] & "," & " " & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![guardian Zip] & " "
'        .TypeText Text:=UserForm1.TextBox5.Value
        .typeParagraph
'        .TypeText Text:=UserForm1.TextBox6.Value
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify ' 0
        .ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 36
'Examples of including a field on same subform as button (letter), and on a different subform (demographics)
        With WDApp
            With .Selection
        .TypeText Text:="The team met on " _
                & Me![date-team-met] _
                & " to review the request for the participant " _
                & Forms![AdverseAction]![Participant Name] & ".  " _
                & "The request was not approved, either partially or in full for the following reasons pursuant to " _
                & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![rule2] & ": " & " "
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
                .TypeText Text:=Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![actiontype2] & ".  " _
                & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![casereview] & " "
'& Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![Participant Name] & " "
'TextBox4 is Guardian/Participant Address
'                & Letter1.TextBox4.Value
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        End With
        End With

'CheckBox1 is "Request Denied In Full"
        If Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![fulldenial] = 1 Then
        With WDApp
            With .Selection
        .TypeText Text:="The request for an IBA change was denied in full for the following reason: " _
            & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![denial] _
            & ", and therefore the IBA amount will not change." & " "
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
            End With
        End With
        End If
'OptionButton15 indicates Temp for the new IBA amount if true
       If Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![IBAstatus].Value = 1 Then
        With WDApp
            With .Selection
        .TypeText Text:="The new temporary IBA amount will be $" _
        & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![NewIBA] _
        & "  ending on " & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![tempIBAdate] & "." & " "
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
            End With
        End With
        End If

'OptionButton14 indicates Perm for the new IBA amount if true
       If Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![IBAstatus].Value = 2 Then
        With WDApp
            With .Selection
        .TypeText Text:="The new permanent IBA amount will be $" _
        & Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-letter]![NewIBA] & "." & " "
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
            End With
        End With
        End If

        .Font.Size = 10
        .Font.Italic = True

        .TypeText Text:="A request for reconsideration of this decision may be submitted to the Division Administrator if one of the following conditions is documented and supported in the request: 1) Information presented in the case was misrepresented; 2) Information was not represented to the fullest extent needed; 3) There was a misapplication of Division standards or policy in the case; or 4) The criteria for the case was misunderstood."
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="Wyoming Medicaid Rules state that the participant has 30 calendar days from the date of the adverse action to request a hearing if s/he disagrees with this decision by submitting a written request for an administrative hearing to the Division Administrator. The person may have an attorney, a relative, a friend, or other spokesperson, including him or herself, represented at this hearing.  The following information shall be included in the hearing request: 1) A statement of request for an administrative hearing regarding the denial; 2) The reasons why the denied request should be approved or allowed; 3) The issues to be raised at the hearing; 4) The request must be signed; and 5) The request must be typed or legibly printed."
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="If a request for an administrative hearing concerning this action is submitted timely and appropriately, the Developmental Disabilities Division will contract with the Office of Administrative Hearings who will notify him/her of the date, time and place of the hearing and other relevant information. Rules pertaining to administrative hearing procedures are located in Wyoming Medicaid Rules, Chapter 4, Section 7."
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Italic = False
        .TypeText Text:="Please contact me with questions or concerns you may have in regards to this decision."
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 210
        .TypeText Text:="Sincerely,"
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        With WDApp
            With .Selection
        .TypeText Text:=Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![Participant Support Specialist] & " "
'        .TypeText Text:=UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value
        .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="Participant Support Specialist"
         .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="6101 Yellowstone Road, Suite 220"
        .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:="Cheyenne, WY 82002"

            End With
        End With

'Removed similar code for each PSS
'        If UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value = "Brett Wilson" Then
'        With WDApp
'            With .Selection
'        .TypeParagraph
'        .TypeText Text:=ws.Cells(19, 1).Value
'            End With
'        End With
'        End If

        .typeParagraph
        .typeParagraph
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
'CheckBox23 is "Participant has Guardian"
'TextBox3 is Guardian Name
'TextBox4 is Guardian/Participant Address
        If Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![guardian].Value = 1 Then
        With WDApp
            With .Selection

        .TypeText Text:="C:"
        .typeParagraph
        .TypeText Text:=Forms![AdverseAction]![aa-subform-demographics]![CASE MANAGER] & " "
        .typeParagraph

            End With
        End With
        End If
'        Else

'ComboBox1 is Participant Name
'TextBox4 is Guardian/Participant Address
'        With WDApp
'            With .Selection
'        .TypeText Text:="C:"
'        .TypeParagraph
'        .TypeText Text:=UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
'        .TypeParagraph
'        .TypeText Text:=UserForm1.TextBox4.Text
'            End With
'        End With
'        End If

End With
    End With

'Save today's date
'Letter1.TextBox9.Value = Date

   Exit Sub
Exit_btnGenLetter_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_btnGenLetter_Click:
    MsgBox "btnGenLetter_Click: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_btnGenLetter_Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    Dim oReference As Access.Reference
    For Each oReference In Access.References

        If oReference.Name Like strReferenceName Then
            boolReferenceExists = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    ' If the Reference does not exist ( and it should not )
    ' Add it to the VBA Project
    If boolReferenceExists = False Then
        Set oReference = References.AddFromFile(strReferenceFile)
    End If
```

Where strReferenceFile is the full path and filename you need to point to.